# Google Sheet How to show a Warning or a Modal with input when a cell has data in it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically what i'm trying to say is, this is a spreadsheet for trucks with trailers, if someone inputs a trailer in cell B, can i make it to throw a popup or a Modal or a warning that cell E should have a truck assigned to it, or data and not allow the user to leave cell E empty?. Appreciate the help. how can i do this with a script?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFdJk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y9Q9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need appscript for that, you can easily do it using data validation.

1. Select range `B:B` and open `Data Validation` dialog box.
2. Select `Custom formula is` in criteria.
3. Use this custom formula `=$E1<>""` , select `Reject Input`. And set custom validation text to show when user violate the above condition.

[image]

Comment: For some reason this is not working, its shows the Reject in both columns

Comment: You've to select only B column...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    if(e.range.offset(0,3).getValue() == '') {
      e.range.offset(0,3).setValue("Please Assign Truck Number Here");
      e.source.toast('Please Assign Truck',"Truck Assignment",15);
    }
  }
}
```

- Dont forget to edit the sheet name

Comment: Hey Thank you Cooper for your help, for for some reason its throwing an error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:2

Comment: I edited the sheet name

Comment: Just load it into script editor.  Go to you page and edit something in column B and hopefully it will work for you as it did for me.  You can run these from the script editor unless you provide the event object

Comment: sorry i'm not that good with scripts, but i loaded it and trying to edit in column B and nothing pops up

Comment: i can share the link with you if you want to give it a try and add you as editor

Comment: Try editing something  in columnB row two or larger

Comment: I copied the script and pasted it into the script editor, changed sheet name to Sheet0 and went to Sheet0 and typed something in B5 and it worked.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pjmz-fwin8KYwh1ec0G_P-l567TMmhprZ6iGtNoxmU8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here you can give it a try, maybe i'm doing something wrong

Comment: I can't see your extensions tab

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kmzjg5mrWvVW7MFa8vXpTgcAM5nebh4JwsC4rSUzj84/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it was in xls format, i just converted it to gsheet, try the new link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kmzjg5mrWvVW7MFa8vXpTgcAM5nebh4JwsC4rSUzj84/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's working now in situations where D is blank.  You can't really use a modal in an onEdit because it must finish in 30 seconds.